# Unable to connect to mysql db with JPA (java persistance)

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jpa

I'm fairly new to Java--though, coming from PHP + JS. I aim to make a CRUD (+MVC) with Java Servlets.

I am using *Java EE 7*. I based some of my patterns here with [*this*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdKTxaHBOdA) and [*that*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdKTxaHBOdA&index=14&list=UUdFttVqX3UDsia9U8mcJzUg) (both have the same final files).

So, I am implementing MVC, and I can't seem to make my code to work. JPA seems to be the main issue; I can't fetch anything from the database.

[Here's the repository](https://bitbucket.org/srph/java-mvc-jpa-test) (really small project -- 7~8 classes). [Models](https://bitbucket.org/srph/java-mvc-jpa-test/src/87e4a9d639e8e652d809ec31a3209603e48ad425/src/models/?at=master); [DAO](https://bitbucket.org/srph/java-mvc-jpa-test/src/87e4a9d639e8e652d809ec31a3209603e48ad425/src/dao/?at=master).

I had setup `controllers.Test`(url: /test) to test if I could actually communicate with the database via JPA. However, when I go to /test(`controllers.Test`), an exception is thrown. The same goes for `controllers.NewsEdit`(url: /edit).

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    controllers.Test.doGet(Test.java:36)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
```

When I visit home(url: /; `controller.NewsIndex`), I receive no exceptions -- I get the homepage, but no data at all. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

My SQL files are located in the `/sql` folder. I got `persistent.xml` on `META-INF/`.

Any help or reference would be appreciated. Really need to learn it..

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the code for Test.java? more excatly line 36?

Comment: I have edited the question with links for each file. Does that help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

A lil explanation about NullPointerException.

When the variable (in this case `private NewsDAO newsDAO;`) hasn't been initialized, that "pointer" is pointing to nothing in memory. Then when you try to call a method, there is nothing there and the NPE happens.

The problem here is that private NewsDAO newsDAO; is not being injected by the container and therefore when you call `newsDAO.all();` newDAO is null and throws the exception.

CDI Injection only happens for components managed by the containers. I'm a spring guy so I'm not sure where to go here. Try to figure out if your NewsDAO is being loaded by the container.

Tomcat is a web container... You need a full Application server with an EJB container to run your example. Try to download and run on glassfish, JBoss or any other full app server.

more info here.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server#Java_application_servers

and

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html

Comment: But, does everything, at least, seem fine? I'll give it a try

Comment: What are you using to run you app?

Comment: I am using Eclipse Java EE 7 with Tomcat.

Comment: Bingo... Tomcat is a web container... You need a full Application server with an EJB container to run your example. Try to download and run on glassfish, JBoss or any other full app server.

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way--this may seem off topic--does Spring provide a great design pattern to work with (less burden of problems such as this)?

Comment: Spring is a more self contained framework. EJBs are part of a bigger platform. So in your case, it might be easier to start with some Spring examples running on Tomcat so you don't need too much.